# How do you add resource packs in Minecraft education edition?

Tags: minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-education-edition

I would like it if you could please add **details** and **steps** Also, I already looked in settings like how it said.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what? Please add that to your post.

Comment: Well, I read the instructions, and it told me to go in settings but, you know

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this](https://educommunity.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360073309131-How-to-download-resource-packs) post on the Minecraft Education Edition forum which states:

> **Minecraft: Education Edition does not officially support mods or
> resource packs.** This version of the game was designed for schools to
> use in class and as such to make sure the game stays secure it does
> not officially support any add-ons. The Bedrock and Java versions of
> the game do support these so if you are wanting to use them you can in
> those versions!